# Submit php form

Tags: php, sql, forms

I'm writing a php code where the user enter various details and then submits them in a form. But, when I submit it, I'm getting this as an error:

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user
>   'sifeiitd'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   /home/sifeiitd/public_html/wh.php on line 95
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server
>   could not be established in /home/sifeiitd/public_html/wh.php on line
>   95

My php code is

```
<?php
                //include the connection file

                require_once('functions/connection.php');
                require_once('functions/functions.php');

                $display_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM eportal");

                    echo "<table id='pageTable'><thead><tr><th>Item code</th><th>Image</th><th>Description</th><th>Cost</th></tr></thead>";
                    echo "<tbody>";
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($display_query)){
                        print "<tr><td>".$row['itemid']."</td><td>"."</td><td>".$row['description']."</td><td>";
                        print "&#8377;".$row['cost']."</td></tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</tbody>";
                    echo "</table>";
                    mysql_close($connection);

            ?>
            <?php

            //save the data on the DB and send the email

            //If the user has submitted the form
            if($_POST['submit']){
                //protect the posted value then store them to variables
                $name = protect($_POST['name']);
                $email = protect($_POST['email']);
                $contact=protect($_POST['contact']);
                $itemid=protect($_POST['itemid']);
                $itemquantity=protect($_POST['itemquantity']);
                $ip = gethostbyname($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
                $message = protect($_POST['message']);
                //Check if the username or password boxes were not filled in
                if(!$name || !$email || !$contact || !$itemid){
                    //if not display an error message
                    echo "<center>Fields marked with <strong>&#40; &#42; &#421</strong> are mandatory!</center>";
                    }else{
                    //if the were continue checking
                        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `wh_order` (`name`, `email`, `contact`, `itemid`, `itemquantity`, `ip`,`message`) VALUES('".$name."','".$email."','".$contact."','".$itemid."','".$itemquantity."','".$ip."','".$message."')");
                         //send the email with the order
                         if($result)
                            {
                                //send the email

                                $to = "ps@xyz.com";
                                $subject = "New order for Weaving Hope";

                                //headers and subject
                                $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                                $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
                                $headers .= "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n";

                                $body = "New contact<br />";
                                $body .= "Name: ".$name."<br />";
                                $body .= "Email: ".$email."<br />";
                                $body .= "Contact No.: ".$contact."<br />";
                                $body .= "Item Id: ".$itemid."<br />";
                                $body .= "Quantity: ".$itemquantity."<br />";
                                $body .= "Comment: ".$message."<br />";
                                $body .= "IP: ".$ip."<br />";

                                mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

                                //ok message

                                echo "Your message has been sent";
                            }
                        }
                    }
            ?>
```

Comment: it sounds as though this code will be running fine but that there is an error in your connection file. Either the DB name, path, username or pass are incorrect.

Comment: You used the wrong database credentials. Also, where is `protect` defined? It sounds like some self-written anti-SQLi thing. If it is, **do not do that** - you should use `mysql_real_escape_string` at least. These days, the preferred (and most secure method) is to use parameterised queries with MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: I fixed the errors. It now accepts all the inputs. I've also received the mail. But the database hasn't been updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Access denied for user 'sifeiitd'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Looks like a pretty clear error to me. Check your `mysql_connect()` statement, probably in `connection.php`.

Comment: I fixed the errors. It now accepts all the inputs. I've also received the mail. But the database hasn't been updated.

Comment: @PrateekSachan you don't issue an `update` statement. Do you mean the data isn't inserted into the database? Then check (echo) your insert query.

Comment: Sorry, and yes, the data isn't being inserted in the database though I'm receiving the email with the submitted values.